# How do I get the current keyboard language?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to get the current keyboard language from the language bar:

[image]

I want to do this in real-time. How?

Edit:
form load:

```
Timer1.Start()
```

```
Public Sub MyCurrentInputLanguage()
    Dim myCurrentLanguage As InputLanguage = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage
    Me.Text = "Current input language is: " & _
        myCurrentLanguage.Culture.EnglishName
End Sub
```

the timer:

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

 MyCurrentInputLanguage()

end sub
```

how can i update my textbox when the user pressing "Alt+Shift"?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage.currentinputlanguage%28v=vs.90%29). The link at MSDN gives this example:

```
CurrLang = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage
```

Here are the details regarding [`InputLanguage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage%28v=vs.90%29).

You can detect the change at runtime (without using a timer), using the [`Form.InputLanguageChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.inputlanguagechanged.aspx) event. (Example from MSDN link cited.)

```
Private Sub Form1_InputLanguageChanged(sender as Object, e as InputLanguageChangedEventArgs) _ 
  Handles Form1.InputLanguageChanged

    Dim messageBoxVB as New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    messageBoxVB.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "InputLanguage", e.InputLanguage)
    messageBoxVB.AppendLine()
    messageBoxVB.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "Culture", e.Culture)
    messageBoxVB.AppendLine()
    messageBoxVB.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "CharSet", e.CharSet)
    messageBoxVB.AppendLine()
    MessageBox.Show(messageBoxVB.ToString(),"InputLanguageChanged Event")

End Sub
```

(Thanks to HansPassant for the info.)

Comment: i tried this code, i put the code in timer event and when i changing the language my label remains with the same content. look at my edit.

Comment: i want to get the current languege in real time and update my label if the user changed the language by Alt+Shit.

Comment: The change only affects the current thread that's running, and those started after it. I don't have any information available on how to update it after your code has already started running - sorry.

Comment: Use the Form.InputLanguageChanged event.

Comment: @Hans, if you want to add  that as an answer and include the content of mine, I'll delete mine afterward. (Drop me a comment to let me know.)

Comment: Please feel free to merge it in your answer, that's why I posted the comment.

Comment: @HansPassant: Done (with credit given where due). Thanks for the info; I hadn't had the need to use that event, so I hadn't even noticed it.